# PHP Spreadsheet modify one sheet without corrupting others

Tags: php, formula, spreadsheet, xlsx

Is there any way (may also be some other PHP based tool) to add data to one sheet or to replace one sheet without modifying the other sheets in the same XLSX file? Or maybe to merge two sheets from separate files to two sheets in one file?

I only need to add rows to one sheet that only contains plain data. The problem is that there are complex formulas in another sheet, which causes PHP Spreadsheet to throw a fatal error.

> Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Exception: Dashboard!B12 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occurred

It reads and writes the file if I use setReadDataOnly or setLoadSheetsOnly, but then obviously the sheet with formulas is broken or missing. Any ideas to work around this? Thanks!